# Views + VBO + User Point + Rules action incorrect

Tags: rules, views, userpoints

I make views(type:node) to grant user point with VBO and Rules but when I select users to grant point then point was grant to one user (I think current user).

but when I change views type to user , I select users to grant point is correct. (I want to use views type:node because I want to filter somethings with PHP filter )

Can I solve this problem?

sorry for my english skill.

Thank you.

---

*Update : sorry I'm confuse about it.
I can solve it.*

I've set Rules set 
argument:content (before this I add argument content and user)

Do:
- Load content author
- Grant points to a user

Thank you

Comment: Can you add the exported code of your view?

Comment: Please answer your question by creating a new answer and accept it as the solution.  Answering your own questions is encouraged if you are able to.